# How to use enum as a type?

Tags: objective-c, enums

Say inside of a class `Card`, you have declared

```
typedef enum {
  CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
} Suit
```

and a

```
typedef enum {
  SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT ..
} Value
```

and a designated initializer

```
-(id) initWithValue: (Value) c andSuit: (Suit) s;
```

How then would you use this initializer from outside of a class?

I tried:

```
[Card alloc] initWithValue: (Card) Value.SIX andSuit: (Card) Suit.HEARTS];
```

Please assist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Card *card = [[Card alloc] initWithValue: SIX andSuit: HEARTS];
```

Answer (score 5):

I'll give an expanded answer. Your code will be a lot more readable if you follow standard obj-c naming conventions.

Generally, you would adopt a conventional naming scheme for your enumeration using your class name followed by a relevant type name such as:

```
typedef enum {
    CardSuitClubs,
    CardSuitDiamonds,
    CardSuitHearts,
    CardSuitSpades
} CardSuit;

typedef enum {
    CardValueTwo,
    ...,
    CardValueAce
} CardValue;
```

Then, you include `card.h` where you need it and use your initializer as follows:

```
Card *card = [[Card alloc] initWithCardValue:CardValueAce andCardSuit:CardSuitSpades];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just this:

```
[[Card alloc] initWithValue:SIX andSuit:HEARTS];
```